# Nginx, Gunicorn и unix-сокеты

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

В данный момент изучаю книгу по TDD, и сталкнулся с проблемой - nginx никак не хочет заводиться с unix-сокетами. Делаю все по гайду:

- sitename далее - название моего домена

*/etc/nginx/sites-avalible/sitename*

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name sitename;

location /static/ {
    alias /home/malomalsky/sites/sitename/static;
    }

location / {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/sitename.socket;
    }}
```

Запускаю gunicorn:

```
../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn  --bind unix:/tmp/sitename.socket superlists.wsgi:application
```

Делаю все, естественно, по книге. В ответ получаю 502.
Сама машина хостится в Azure. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Comment: В сторону чтения логов nginx

Comment: или в сторону логов gunicorn. или так попробуйте `proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/sitename.socket:/;`, но вряд ли

Comment: 2021/01/11 13:31:16 [error] 4359#4359: *202 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: --------, server: sitename, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "sitename"

Comment: Забыл добавить - сам gunicorn запускается без ошибок

Comment: Откуда у вас 127.0.0.1:8000 вдруг взялся?  Может вы забыли перезапустить nginx?

Comment: Перезапускал и Nginx, и саму виртуальную машину...

Comment: `sudo nginx -t` что пишет?

Comment: Что конфиги в норме

Comment: А `sudo nginx -T`?

Comment: Тогда можно сразу что-то вроде `sudo nginx -T | grep -C 10 127.0.0.1:8000`